# What's the use of setuptools in Google App Engine with Python 2.7

Tags: python, google-app-engine, setuptools

Can somebody explain me how to use the setuptools inside python in google app engine. It's listed as Third Party Libraries in the docs. How do i utilize it, if i dont have access to the filesystem?

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setuptools` provides the [`pkg_resources` module](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html), letting you load resources from python eggs and look up metadata.

You can use this to load resources from eggs you include in your deployment.